# Melhor prática para registrar log do sistema

Tags: c#, .net, log

Qual a melhor prática para se registrar um *log* de sistema?

```
    public void inserirLog(string Acao)
        {

        StringBuilder csql = new StringBuilder();
        csql.Append("insert into Log (Acao,data) values(");
        csql.Append(@"""" + Acao + @""",");
        csql.Append("'" + DateTime.Now + "')");
        Conexao conn= new Conexao();
        conn.ExecutarComando(csql.ToString());
        }
```

Hoje faço desse maneira, ou seja, a cada ação que quero que apareça um *log*, gero um `insert` no banco de dados. Essa maneira além de custosa gera muitas requisições ao banco de dados então acredito não ser a mais viável, estava pensando em registrar cada *log* em um arquivo texto, então depois transmitir esse arquivo, será que essa seria uma boa forma?

Obs:. Os *logs* são para registro de ação , por exemplo: "Abriu tela X", "Logou no Sistema", "Saiu do Sistema", etc.

Meu sistema possui muitas funcionalidades, então esse *log* seria para mapear o que vem sendo utilizado pelos clientes.

Comment: Não tem como definir o objeto `Conexao con` para uma váriavel `private` e se ela já estiver setada, você só reaproveitara a mesma "conexão" se houver mais de um LOG na mesma requisição?

Comment: Obrigado pela Resposta, vou tentar seguir o conselho do amigo abaixo, mas mesmo assim obrigado pela opinião. Bem visto, não preciso instanciar a conexão a cada log poderia ter utilizado a mesma.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A melhor prática é não reinventar a roda. É usar uma ferramenta de *log* que foi bem pensada e testada por profissionais que se dedicam a isto. E usar estas ferramentas prontas de acordo com as recomendações específicas.

Claro que que alguns casos é interessante criar um sistema próprio, mas você precisa ter um motivo para isto. Eu não acho que soluções prontas resolvem todos os problemas. Mas não parece ser o seu caso, acho que você poderia muito bem usar algo pronto que resolve essas questões que você está preocupado.

Estas ferramentas oferecem soluções para realizar *buffering*, fazer balanceamento de carga e resolução de falhas, escrevem assincronamente e permite escolher vários alvos para persistir o *log*.

Antes de passar algumas soluções quero dizer que *log* em banco de dados tem que ser bem pensado mesmo, imagine que o banco de dados pode ser uma grande fonte de problemas em certas circunstâncias (a não ser que seja um SQLite, por exemplo), aí você precisaria *logar* os problemas ocorridos no seu *log*. Complica, né?.

Alguns *frameworks* de *log* conhecidos para .NET:

- [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) - um dos mais conhecidos e usados baseado no Log4J, parece abandonado.
- [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) - Um dos mais modernos e conhecidos. O único que eu usei de fato e parece ser o mais popular até porque também costuma ser o mais eficiente.
- [Enterprise Library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff648951(v=pandp.10)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) - Solução oficial da Microsoft mas não resolve bem algumas coisas.
- [Elmah](https://elmah.io/) - Bastante recomendado para uso com ASP.NET. Muito simples de usar porque ele injeta o que é necessário, acho um pouco pesado.
- [.NET Logging Framework](http://www.theobjectguy.com/dotnetlog/) - Outro bem recomendado e tem algumas características diferentes - não sei se existe ainda.
- [SeriLog](http://serilog.net/) - Não conheço mas é mais um para investigar e ver se te atende melhor, muita gente usa e considera bom.
- [Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET) - É uma opção mais nova e moderna mas quase não usado até onde eu percebi.
- [ASP.NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) - Se precisa de algo simples e para web não precisa de nada externo, o próprio ASP.NET tem um sistema de *log* simples.
- [.NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) - Para aplicações em geral tem uma pequena ajuda para cenários bem simples.

Existem outros mais simples mas que são pouco suportados e vários abandonados. Existem também algumas soluções mais completas mas pagas, raramente valem à pena.

Em geral essas soluções só cuidam do *log* em si, exigindo que você invoque sua execução não de interceptação que provavelmente requerem ferramentas de reescrita do *assembly* usando técnicas de orientação a aspectos. Veja resposta complementar do Cigano Morrison Mendez.

Existem ainda algumas ferramentas para analisar estes *logs*, o que ajuda justificar a escolha por uma solução padrão.

- [Sentinel](https://github.com/yarseyah/sentinel) - Open Source
- [Chainsaw](https://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/2.x/) - Open Source
- [Gibraltar](http://www.gibraltarsoftware.com/loupe/extensions/nlog) - Gratuito
- [LogEntries](https://logentries.com/)- Pago
- [Reflect Insight](http://www.reflectsoftware.com/) - Pago

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu adicionaria a esta lista o TraceSource... não sei pq utilizar uma ferramenta de terceiros quando o proprio dotNEt disponibiliza uma solução bem completa.

Comment: Obrigado irei dar uma olhada nesses Framework.

O que necessito é apenas, salvar cada log de ação para saber o que os clientes estão utilizando no sistema.

Por exemplo: "Abriu tela X", "Logou no Sistema", "Saiu do Sistema", etc.

Obrigado pela resposta por enquanto.

Comment: Como a pergunta possivelmente envolve interceptação de ações específicas, seria bom aprimorar a resposta pra incluir o Castle Windsor e o Castle Dynamic Proxy.

Comment: @TobyMosque a sugestão é boa mas para ter uma solução de *log* robusta e mais poderosa precisaria de mais que este recurso. Posso estar enganado mas parece que isto não foi feito para funcionar como um *log* do dia-a-dia.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez responda com esta parte. Embora tenha lido alguma coisa eu não os conheço, provavelmente falaria besteira.

Comment: @bigown Vou complementar a sua.

Comment: @bigown, eu particulamente não vejo muita diferença entre o TraceSource o Log4Net, pelo menos com a minha pouca experiencia com ambos. a unica grande vantagem do TraceSource, é a configuração inicial que é muito simples.

Comment: Acho que ele quis log para eventos de DB...

Comment: Os logs são para registro de ação mesmo, or exemplo: "Abriu tela X", "Logou no Sistema", "Saiu do Sistema", etc

Meu sistema possui muitas funcionalidades, então esse log seria para mapear o que vem sendo utilizado pelos clientes.

Hoje salvo cada ação no BD, e depois gero um csv e transmito para o servidor.

Comment: @Rod não foi o que eu entendi, em geral *log* dos eventos do DB são gerados pelo próprio DB, ninguém precisa fazer nada a não ser consultá-lo e mantê-lo.

Comment: Entendi, pensei que fosse para auditoria, mas as ações, você poderia usar google analyctics, saberá quais as urls mais acessadas...se fosse só para verificar o que mais ele está usando...

Comment: @bigown sim...+1 para sua resposta, gostei do NLog, principalmente por enviar e-mail quando ocorre erros, isso é muito útil ao meu ver =)

Comment: @AndrewAlex neste caso você usará a FileSystem como alvo. O envio deverá ser feito de forma independente. Mas estude todas as opções e teste para ver o que melhor te atende.

Comment: @bigown Os links passados seriam frameworks de logs ?
Como ele registraria uma ação minha?

Comment: @Marconi sim, são, em geral você chama um método dele passando a informação que você quer *logar*. Mas você pode automatizar isto. Tem vantagens e desvantagens em fazer isto. Veja resposta do Cigano para ver uma das formas mais conhecidas de como fazer a interceptação da execução e "logar sozinho". A documentação de alguns deles também dão dicas de como fazer isto.

Comment: @bigown Muito obrigado eu não sabia nem dá existência disso, com certeza estarei estudando alguns.

Answer (score 12):

Como o que você quer registrar envolve interceptação de ações, o correto é combinar alguma solução de log (resposta do @Maniero) com *proxy* dinâmico, sendo esta interceptação feita pelo Framework [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://docs.castleproject.org/Tools.DynamicProxy.ashx). Entretanto, por ser uma aplicação Web, você terá que registrar os gatilhos usando um contenedor (*container*) de inversão de controle, neste caso, o [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx).

No tutorial do próprio Castle Windsor, [na parte 5 dele ensina a fazer exatamente o que você quer](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-Tutorial-Part-Five-Adding-logging-support.ashx).

Se você quer registrar apenas persistências e seleções em banco e sua ideia é usar o Entity Framework, use o [EntityFramework.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Extended), [que tem o recurso de log de auditoria](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended/wiki/Audit-Log).

Comment: No meu caso a aplicação é WinForms, sendo que vou salvar esse arquivo de log diariamente e depois transmitir para o meu servidor ftp("Caso o cliente esteja conectado"). Então sua sugestão não entraria no contexto correto?

Comment: @AndrewAlex E por que não entraria?

Comment: Vou estudar um pouco esse então também, entendi errado achei que quando você comentou "por ser uma aplicação Web" estava se referindo que precisaria utilizar uma tecnologia Web.

Comment: Não, não. Apenas diagnostiquei o que você estaria usando e dei alguns atalhos ;)

Comment: @AndrewAlex esta solução é para você pode automatizar a execução do *log* assim você nem precisa ficar chamando nada, você não mexe no seu código. ele *log* por conta própria. Pode ser que você não precise disto mas pode ser bastante útil. Realmente entenda suas vantagens antes de descartar, pode lhe poupar bastante trabalho.

Comment: @bigown Certo, não irei descartar, Agora com essas respostas Consegui bastante material de estudo. E vi que preciso entender melhor do que se trata o "LOG" em si.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Você teria mais algum exemplo para utilizar o Castle Dynamic? Não consegui entender como "capturo" automaticamente a execução do log. 
Utilizando o log4net, já consegui um avanço considerável, porém agora resta automatizar o processo de *logar*.

Comment: @AndrewAlex Seria por interceptação de método, [conforme descrito aqui](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-Tutorial-Part-Five-Adding-logging-support.ashx). Repare que a solução combina o Castle Windsor com o Castle Dynamic Proxy.