# Gravar log de acesso em aplicação ASP NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Tenho um site ASP NET MVC e preciso gravar no banco de dados todo vez que alguém acessar gravando o ip e a data de acesso do cliente, existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Não quero gravar cada pagina que o cliente entrar, apenas gravar quando abrir o site, tipo o cliente abriu o navegado e acessou o site ai eu gravo.

Gravar somente a segunda vez do mesmo cliente se ele acessar por outro navegador ou se ele fechar o navegador e abrir novamente.

Abrir o site em uma nova aba sendo que ele já esta com o site aberto em outra aba acredito que não deva contar.

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52240/101. Nada específico, mas a pergunta também não. Ou é duplicata ou parece ampla.

Comment: Poderia adicionar mais detalhes? O seu site tem login? Irá contar se acessar qualquer tela?

Comment: Meu site não tem login, qualquer tela conta se for a primeira vez que o site for acessada. se ele acessar www.meusite.com.br então conta se for a primeira vez, se ele acessar direto www.meusite.com.br/MinhaPagina então conta se for a primeira vez

Comment: Eu não sei como identificar se é a primeira vez para gravar no banco, é somente isso que eu preciso. To vendo aqui que talvez eu consiga fazer com ActionFilters, mas como posso fazer um if verificando se é a primeira vez do cliente no site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `Global.asax`, dentro do método `Session_Start()` faça a codificação para gravar por `SessionId` (`Session.SessionID`), um ***log*** de informações.

***Vou propor um modo:***

Crie um base de dados com o seguinte layout:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log](
    [SessionId] [nvarchar](24) NOT NULL,
    [SessionDataTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ServerIP] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Log] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SessionId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
  IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

dentro do método `Session_Start()`:

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
    string SessionId = Session.SessionID;
    string ServerIp = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    DateTime SessionDataTime = DateTime.Now;
    using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=Db;User Id=sa;Password=senha;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"))
    using (SqlCommand Command = Conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        Conn.Open();
        Command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Log WHERE SessionId=@SessionId";
        Command.Parameters.Add("SessionId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 24).Value = SessionId;
        if (int.Parse(Command.ExecuteScalar().ToString()) == 0)
        {
            Command.Parameters.Clear();
            Command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Log (SessionId,ServerIp,SessionDataTime) VALUES(@SessionId,@ServerIp,@SessionDataTime)";
            Command.Parameters.Add("SessionId", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 24).Value = SessionId;
            Command.Parameters.Add("ServerIp", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15).Value = ServerIp;
            Command.Parameters.Add("SessionDataTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = SessionDataTime;
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

só será inserido um novo registro mediante a renovação da sua `SessionId`.

Comment: Esse Session_Start() resolveu meu problema, não usei seu código por completo pq uso MySql mas o Session_Start() salvou. Obrigado

Comment: Opa @MauricioFerraz, obrigado, só não fiz com MySQL porque na questão não tinha um tag dizendo isso... se tivesse tinha implementado, mas, tenho certeza que você já tinha uma rotina ... !

Answer (score 2):

Irei postar uma resposta com a forma mais simples que eu conheço, e que pode ser utilizada em outras linguagens.

A lógica é simples. Você cria um **cookie** que será expirado por session, assim sempre que fechar o navegador ele será excluído. E em seu `_Layout.cshtml` você faz a verificação se o **cookie** existe. Se existir não faz nada, mas se não existir você faz uma requisição e salva o que desejar.

Então, vamos aos códigos.

Primeiro, vamos entender um pouco mais sobre como trabalhar com **cookies** [nesta pergunta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10730362/4843158).

Feito isso, vamos ao nosso arquivo `_Layout.cshtml` (ou o arquivo de layout que é utilizado em todas as páginas) e utilizaremos o seguinte código:

```
   <script>
        //Função para ler o cookie
        function readCookie(name) {
            var nameEQ = name + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
                if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
            }
            return null;
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Buscando o cookie
            var NewAccess = readCookie('NewAccess');
            //Verificando se o cookie existe
            if (!NewAccess) {
                document.cookie = "NewAccess=true; expires=0;";
                $.post('@Url.Action("SalvarLogin","Home")')//Coloque a URL para salvar os dados
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Como a pergunta é em `Asp.Net MVC`, basta fazer isso no Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SalvarLogin()
    {
        //Método para salvar aqui
        return null;//Retorno que dessejar
    }
```

Desta forma sempre irá realizar a verificação que deseja.

> Devo ressaltar que, logicamente, se a pessoa limpar os cookies, ele irá considerar como um novo acesso.