# Ignorar uma exception específica

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exceção

Em meu `try-catch`, quero gravar a exceção ocorrida dentro do um objeto (para efeito de histórico, necessário para a regra de negócio, já que este trecho se dá em um processamento via integração com fontes externas).

Para isso, preciso me certificar no `catch` que a exceção não foi de banco de dados ou do meu ORM, pois se não daria uma exceção dentro da exceção... seria um *crash* feio e pimba, sistema fora do ar.

Então, seria mais ou menos isso:

```
Try {
    //Cógido
}
catch (exception ex)
{
     //VERIFICAR SE NÃO É UMA EXCEÇÃO DE BD (MEU CASO ENTITY FRAMEWORK)
}
```

Existe esta possibilidade? Como eu poderia fazer isso de uma forma mais genérica possível?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você está querendo ignorar a exceção mais importante. Existem uma quantidade enorme de exceções que podem ocorrer nesse caso. Bons sistemas de *log* tratam os problema que podem ocorre nele próprio por isso [pense em usar um deles](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52240/101).

Se realmente quiser fazer isso pode filtrar as exceções:

```
catch (Exception ex) when (!(ex is DbException) && !(ex is EntityException)) {
    //faz o que deseja aqui
}
```

Mas talvez o mais correto é tratar essas exceções antes:

```
catch (ex DbException)) {
    //faz o que deseja aqui
} catch (ex EntityException) {
    //faz o que deseja aqui
} catch (Exception ex) {
    //faz o que deseja aqui
}
```

Espero que não tenha outros problemas. [Raros os programadores que usam exceções da maneira correta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o?sort=votes&pageSize=50).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/DoubleExceptionPreventionForLog.cs).

Comment: Show de bola @bigown. Já uso o Elmah. Este caso aí foi mto específico e somente para gravar efeitos (ou defeitos) do processamento durante a integração. Para histórico. Parece feio a solução mas foi super consciente.

Comment: Importante lembrar que o `is` verifica toda a estrutura de herança do objeto.

Comment: @jbueno mas a intenção de filtrar é justamente pegar a hierarquia toda. Eu só errei no segundo exemplo porque copiei e colei e esqueci de tirar o `is` que n~em cabe ali :) Arrumado.

Answer (score 6):

É só você saber qual o tipo da *exception* que quer ignorar.

Se quiser ignorar uma **`DbException`**, faça o seguinte

```
try 
{ 
}
catch (DbException ex)
{
    //ignorar
}
```