# Captura e tratamento de exceções de forma genérica

Tags: c#, .net, exceção

No geral o mais comum é capturar as *exceptions* específicas e fazer algum tratamento com isso, certo?

Exemplo:

```
try
{
   //Algum trecho de código
}
catch (MyException myException)
{
   //Especifico para este erro
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //Qualquer outra coisa
}
```

Porém, quando o programador não cria um `catch` especifico para sua *exception*, ela acaba sendo captura pelo *exception* genérico.

Exemplo:

```
try
{
   //Algum trecho de código
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //Se aqui a exception fosse uma instancia de MyException
   //o programador não teria acesso à dados importantes da outra exception
   //a menos que ele fizesse uma conversão
   //mas como ele não sabia que poderia ocorrer este erro, não o fez.
}
```

Isso acaba dando problemas, porque em alguns casos, é gravado *log* dessas exceptions em uma tabela no banco de dados, e a informação não fica completa...

O certo nestes casos seria implementar o `catch` especifico, quanto à isso não há dúvidas.

Mas aí vem a dúvida, existe alguma forma de mitigar esse problema? Alguma boa prática?

O que me veio a cabeça, seria implementar uma classe que lidasse com cada uma das exception, assim eu poderia chama um método especifico via *reflection*. Veja:

Classe:

```
public static class ExceptionHandler
{
    public static void Handle(this MyException exp)
    {
      //Aqui faço alguma coisa
    }

    public static void Handle(Exception ex)
    {
       //Aqui outra
    }
}
```

Uso dela:

```
try
{
   //Algum trecho de código
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var baseType = ex.GetType();
    var convertedExp = Convert.ChangeType(ex, baseType);
    var methodInfo = typeof(ExceptionHandler).GetMethod("Handle", new Type[1] { baseType });
    methodInfo.Invoke(convertedExp, new object[1] { convertedExp });
}
```

Não me parece ser uma boa ideia e talvez nem tenho muito o que se fazer...

O que pode ser dito sobre isto?

Comment: sua pergunta não faz muito sentido, existem dezenas de classes que extendem o exception na linguagem, não ter uma exception customizada não significa necessariamente deixa-la para o exception generico, outra coisa, lançar uma exception é um baita processo custoso, se puder evitar, evite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fazia tempo que não via uma pergunta tão importante no site.

> No geral o mais comum é capturar as exceptions específicas e fazer algum tratamento com isso, certo?

Se fizer sentido naquele cenário, é sim.

> Porém, quando o programador não cria um `catch` específico para sua *exception*, ela acaba sendo capturada pelo `Exception` genérico.
>
> Isso acaba dando problemas, porque em alguns casos é gravado *log* dessas *exceptions* em uma tabela no banco de dados, e a informação não fica completa...

Não necessariamente, essa é uma possibilidade. Se tiver uma específica e uma genérica juntas, tem chance de ter algo errado aí.

No local específico o comum é ter tratamentos específicos. Para tratamentos genéricos o local costuma ser mais geral.

> O que me veio a cabeça seria implementar uma classe que lidasse com cada uma das *exception*, assim eu poderia chama um método especifico via *reflection*.

Existem várias formas de fazer, quase ninguém foge do arroz com feijão porque não costuma ser necessário.

Inclusive você pode não usar exceção na sua API e evitar até onde dá as exceções na API de terceiros (até do .NET), tem vantagens.

> Não me parece ser uma boa ideia e talvez nem tenho muito o que se fazer... O que acham?

Não vi vantagem em fazer exatamente assim, na verdade parece uma grande gambiarra para não ficar pensando na solução específica. Não é a filosofia do C#.

Assim parece mais adequado (não estou dizendo que é o ideal para qualquer caso):

```
catch (MyException ex) {
    ex.Handle();
}
```

Se quiser pode ter outros `catch`es, inclusive de `Exception` *se fizer mesmo sentido), mas faça explicitamente, mesmo que todos tenham códigos idênticos dentro (duvido porque alguns desses métodos receberão parâmetros). Pode parecer que essas repetições são uma violação do DRY, mas [DRY não é isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101).

```
try {
    //Algum trecho de código
} catch (MyException myException) {
    ex.Handle();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.Handle();
}
```

Apesar de `ex` parecer ser o mesmo código olhando a sintaxe, a semântica dele é diferente porque eles são de tipos diferentes.

Ter uma informação canônica de como manipular uma exceção é algo não só bom, como também fundamental. Erradas são as pessoas que repetem a mesma manipulação por todo o código. Mas só a chamada é normal.

Só não acho ideal usar reflexão. Quase sempre que usa reflexão está fazendo algo errado para economizar digitação ou fazer gambiarra para resolver um problema que não existia de fato.

Dá para fazer com `switch`. Ele deve ser usado como um *pattern matching* de forma muito simples, o compilador lida direitinho para você sem reflexão. Não vou mostrar porque ainda é errado, é trocar uma forma de *switch* que tem consequências adequadas para a situação por outro que funciona, mas cria alguns problemas para alguns cenários (esse foi até o motivo de terem criado as tais [*filter exceptions*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177913/101)).

O `catch` sempre foi uma forma de *pattern matching* com uma semântica mais especializada.

E claro, se tiver algum caso que a manipulação deve ter um comportamento diferente desse padrão que criou na sua classe que centraliza as manipulações, você deve tratar isso. Então deve ter como existir uma versão diferente que não seja o `Handle(MyException)`. Precisa ser um método que manipule essa mesma exceção mas de uma forma diferente:

```
public static void Handle(this MyException exp) {
    //Aqui faço alguma coisa
}
public static void Handle(this MyException exp, string message) {
    //Aqui faço alguma coisa
}
public static void HandleSpecific(this MyException exp) {
    //Aqui faço alguma coisa
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/GeneralHandle.cs).

Também poderia ter um parâmetro que indique o que fazer e internamente terá um `switch` decidindo o que fazer (usando *pattern matching*). Ou pode ter outros mecanismos, estou apenas dando exemplos de como tratar essa situação.

Muitos dirão que nem deve centralizar isso e ter uma classe de manipulação para cada exceção que for tratar, e tem lá seu sentido, só não acho que deva ser assim sempre. Mas muita gente boa faz porque na maioria dos cenários não é problema. Não vou me estender nisso porque não é o foco, existem outras discussões sobre isso no site e em outros lugares, isto é ortogonal ao que está perguntado aqui.

## Desenvolver software é mais complicado do que parece

É o que eu sempre falo, para tomar todas decisões certas precisa entender todos os conceitos de desenvolvimento e combinar todos eles de forma correta em cada caso. É bem complicado fazer isso, muita coisa não é ortogonal.

Eu sou da opinião que as exceções deveriam quase obrigatoriamente ter uma manipulação padrão, mas não foi assim que aconteceu em nenhuma linguagem, eu entendo porque (mas tem solução para o problema que seria isso), mas tem soluções melhores. Também não vou me estender.

Tirando a parte da exceção é algo até bem básico, havia uma época que quase todo programador sabia fazer a abstração e generalização de uma ação em uma função. Hoje as pessoas aprendem por receita de bolo, então elas leem um tutorial que fala para fazer de um jeito muito simples, sem pensar em todas consequências, sem estar se preocupando com o caso concreto, com as interações daquele mecanismo com outros, e aí a pessoa aprende errado. E ela faz um código errado que outras pessoas usarão como referência, e talvez ela faça um outro tutorial ou livro ou vídeo errado. Chega um ponto que a pessoa nem se dá conta que ela está ensinando errado. É como a Covid-19. Contamina tanta gente que o certo começa ser considerado errado por muitos.

É por isso que eu falo para aprender de forma estruturada. Eu tenho várias respostas aqui, especialmente sobre exceções. Se você as ler isoladamente aprenderá errado. Não foi minha intenção, mas a resposta era isolada praquela questão, não pra tudo o que precisava aprender sobre o assunto. Até agora não tinha uma pergunta sobre o que foi postado aqui, ninguém aprendeu nada sobre o DRY de manipulações de exceções.

Note que essa resposta não dá toda informação possível sobre o assunto porque a pergunta não é sobre isso, mas mostra a importância de não repetir código de manipulação quando ele é igual. Tem outros pontos a serem analisados aqui, não tome a resposta como um guia definitivo de como lidar com isso. E leia diversas outras respostas sobre o assunto.

## Conclusão

Eu acho que deve esquecer essa ideia de sempre só capturar `Exception`. Mas é uma solução, é criativa, se feita certinha não acho ela inviável, só não é ideal.

Comment: Realmente, acho que o mais adequado mesmo seria a solução que você deu ali. E com relação à todo o resto, foi bem esclarecedor. Obrigado.